# How to run java programs simultaneously in VS codes

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

I am trying to run a Server and Client in VS codes. The Server and Client are programmed in Java and are in 2 different projects but whenever I try to run both of them simultaneously, VS codes shut the other one down. Can someone please tell me how to run both of them in parallel?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Open both projects in different VS code this will make you run both of them simultaneously

Comment: both project have same port?

Answer (score 0):

Check the [documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/editor/debugging#_multitarget-debugging) on multitarget debugging:

One way is to create a "compounds" section in `launch.json` containing the target you want to debug.

Another way is to launch another session, after you've started a first debug session.